# Using php/javaBridge without running tomcat

Tags: php, laravel, php-java-bridge

Is it possible to run java code with php/JavaBridge but without installing tomcat?

I'm using laravel framework.

Comment: I guess that you only need a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible you need tomcat or another webserver only if you need a servlet container. You can start the bridge without tomcat with the following command.

When you click on the link there is an example in the documentation.

```
#java -classpath JavaBridge.war TestInstallation
```

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/installation.php